# Hierarchical data with CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am sorry if the answer has been posted already, but I was not able to find the answer even after searching.

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[emp](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [mgrid] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

With data

```
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([id], [name], [mgrid]) VALUES (1, N'a', 0)
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([id], [name], [mgrid]) VALUES (2, N'a1', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([id], [name], [mgrid]) VALUES (3, N'a11', 2)
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([id], [name], [mgrid]) VALUES (4, N'a12', 2)
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([id], [name], [mgrid]) VALUES (5, N'a13', 2)
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([id], [name], [mgrid]) VALUES (6, N'a2', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([id], [name], [mgrid]) VALUES (7, N'a3', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([id], [name], [mgrid]) VALUES (8, N'a31', 7)
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([id], [name], [mgrid]) VALUES (9, N'a32', 7)
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([id], [name], [mgrid]) VALUES (10, N'b', 0)
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([id], [name], [mgrid]) VALUES (11, N'b1', 10)
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([id], [name], [mgrid]) VALUES (12, N'b2', 10)
```

And I would like the following output

```
a
    a1
        a11
        a12
        a13
    a2
    a3
        a31
        a32
b
    b1
    b2
```

Is this possible in SQL Server?

Comment: You could concat an empty string in front of it.

Comment: Is this output by print. Or These are different columns ? Do you want this for some specific further processing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/32592/15)

You can use ' ' instead of '+' in the last line to pad a string.

```
with t as
(
  select id,name,mgrid,1 as level,cast(name as varchar(max)) as path 
         from emp where mgrid=0
  union all 
  select emp.id,emp.name,emp.mgrid, t.level+1 as level, 
         t.path+cast(emp.name as varchar(max)) as path

  from emp
  join t on emp.mgrid=t.id
)

select replicate('+', level)+name from t order by path
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with CTE as
(
  select *
    , level = 1
  from emp
  where mgrid = 0
  union all
  select emp.id,
    name = cast(space((level) * 3) + emp.name as varchar(20)),
    emp.mgrid,
    level = level + 1
  from emp
    inner join CTE on CTE.id = emp.mgrid
)
select name
from CTE
order by ltrim(name)
```

Comment: `order by ltrim(name)` will only work if a1,a11,a12 are real names.

Comment: @RaviSingh, true enough... an alternative would be to build a hierarchy path on the fly like the answer from @valex; since he's already done that I'll leave mine as it is and leave the credit with him.

Comment: This will not work as if i change my data whole thing messes up just try to update the record id with 2 gice name z2

Comment: As per my previous comment the solution provided by @valex addresses this and you should investigate his answer further.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CTE (Comnon table expression to achieve this)

check this sample code:

```
declare @emp table(
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [mgrid] [int] NULL
) 


INSERT @emp ([id], [name], [mgrid]) VALUES (1, N'a', 0)
INSERT @emp ([id], [name], [mgrid]) VALUES (2, N'a1', 1)
INSERT @emp ([id], [name], [mgrid]) VALUES (3, N'a11', 2)
INSERT @emp ([id], [name], [mgrid]) VALUES (4, N'a12', 2)
INSERT @emp ([id], [name], [mgrid]) VALUES (5, N'a13', 2)
INSERT @emp ([id], [name], [mgrid]) VALUES (6, N'a2', 1)
INSERT @emp ([id], [name], [mgrid]) VALUES (7, N'a3', 1)
INSERT @emp ([id], [name], [mgrid]) VALUES (8, N'a31', 7)
INSERT @emp ([id], [name], [mgrid]) VALUES (9, N'a32', 7)
INSERT @emp ([id], [name], [mgrid]) VALUES (10, N'b', 0)
INSERT @emp ([id], [name], [mgrid]) VALUES (11, N'b1', 10)
INSERT @emp ([id], [name], [mgrid]) VALUES (12, N'b2', 10);


with cte (id,name, MGRID) as
(
    select id, name,MGRID
    from @emp
    union all
    select c.id, c.name, c.MGRID
    from @emp c
    inner join cte p
        on c.mgrid = P.id
)


SELECT Distinct * FROM CTE
```

Comment: thx i am accepting this answer but i need to write                         SELECT distinct * FROM CTE

Answer (score 1):

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [mgrid] [int] NULL
)

INSERT INTO @temp ([id], [name], [mgrid])
VALUES 
    (1, N'a', 0), (2, N'a1', 1),
    (3, N'a11', 2), (4, N'a12', 2),
    (5, N'a13', 2), (6, N'a2', 1),
    (7, N'a3', 1), (8, N'a31', 7),
    (9, N'a32', 7), (10, N'b', 0),
    (11, N'b1', 10), (12, N'b2', 10)

DECLARE @out VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT *, Lvl = 0, nn = CAST(name AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM @temp
    WHERE mgrid = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.*, c.Lvl + 1, nn = CAST(REPLICATE('   ', c.Lvl + 1) + t.name AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM @temp t
    JOIN cte c ON c.id = t.mgrid
)
SELECT @out = (
    SELECT nn + CHAR(13)
    FROM cte
    ORDER BY LTRIM(nn)
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')

PRINT @out
```

**Output:**

```
a
   a1
      a11
      a12
      a13
   a2
   a3
      a31
      a32
b
   b1
   b2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RCTE AS 
(
    SELECT id, name, mgrid, CAST('' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS blanks , CAST(name AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS ordr
    FROM dbo.emp WHERE mgrid = 0

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT e.id, e.name, e.mgrid, blanks + '   ' AS blanks, ordr + e.name AS ordr 
    FROM dbo.emp e
    INNER JOIN RCTE r ON e.mgrid = r.id
)
SELECT blanks + name FROM RCTE
ORDER BY ordr
```